# Change ngForm field value

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

When i submit my form, i have this function

```
login(form: NgForm)
```

If I try the following

```
console.log(form.value.password); // this works perfect.
```

but this doesn't work

```
form.value.password = ''
```

After failed login i want to reset the password field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**but this doesn't work**

```
form.value.password = ''
```

Because form.value returns you value of the form and it is an read only property part of AbstractControl

From angular2 source code

```
/**
 * The value of the control.
 */
readonly value: any;
```

**You can use reset for your purpose.**

/**
   * Resets the control. Abstract method (implemented in sub-classes).
*/

```
abstract reset(value?: any, options?: Object): void;
```

Usage of setValue or patchValue.

```
this.yourForm.controls['password'].setValue(password)
```

Or you can assign value to whole form

```
this.yourForm.setValue(data);
```

When using setValue on whole form then you have ro provide every control otherwise it throw error like property missing paychValue in other hand can handle if you sending only on element.

Comment: Can I set a value of type File?. For example: *form.controls ['image'].setValue (event.target.files [0])* . I work with Angular 7

Comment: I had forgotten that I should reset the form

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `setValue()` or `patchValue()` methods available on angular form controls/groups, eg

```
form.patchValue({
  username: '', // or whatever fields you have
  password: ''
});
```

see the [docs here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are using template-driven or model-driven forms. This works for both though.

Just use `reset()` for this purpose, so reset that single form control:

```ts
login(form) {
  // do whatever logic, and if login failed, reset like below
  form.controls.password.reset()
}
```

**[DEMO with template-driven form](http://plnkr.co/edit/QTL7wSCb5mLOypD7fsp2?p=preview)**